# Can I leave some loot in "flashback" to pick up in current timeline?

Tags: resident-evil-7

In the course of game some locations can be visited several times under different circumstances.

My question is about

> Visiting Wrecked Ship twice - in Old videotape and in current timeline.

I've noticed, that containers that I've opened with corrosive and looted in my first visit are opened and empty when I got there second time (which seems logical).

I wonder is it possible to open containers on first visit, but leave the loot there for second visit?

Comment: FYI: Your question should make sense without spoilers. If it doesn't, it shouldn't be in spoilers.

Comment: @Frank, I've tried to edit the question. I still don't want to remove spoiler completely, as question could appear in some review queue.

Comment: I understand, but we're in the business of asking, and answering, questions. We don't dance around that. As is, you're trying so hard to circle around it. Just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** Containers are always empty in current timeline.

I did another run today and tested this out.

Here are two locations on 2F in past- one I left with 1 bombs, another with 2:

[image: container 1 old videotape]
[image: container 2 old videotape]

The same places in current timeline - both containers were empty when I got to them:

[image: container 1 current]
[image: container 2 current]